# keyup() not working for Autocompleted field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a textbox that is autocompleted and I'm trying to use this jQuery to grab the content of the text box.

```
$("#textbox").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#insertvalue").text(value);
}).keyup();
```

The code above only works if I type the value, but not when I chose a value from autocomplete suggestion.

How can I make it work for both values I type in the textbox and options I chose from autocomplete.

I was able to get value using this:

```
    $("#textbox").on('autocompletechange change', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#insertvalue").text(value);
}).change();
```

Now, the area where I'm using the selected text only updates when I click somewhere on the page. How can I update the text area immediately value is selected.

Comment: use the `change` event of `autocomplete` when you select from list

Comment: @vispan check updated question.

Comment: Just for check ...try to separate the `autocompletechange` and `change` and remove `change()` from last part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using this

```
 $('#textbox').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
        $('#insertvalue').text(ui.item.value);
 });
```

I get updated value each time I select a value from Autocompleted textbox.